# to get the output as an array not in separate rows in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have written a query, which returns four columns and four columns have values in the separate rows.

But I want is that the query should return me an array for different columns, not values in the separate rows.

The query is:

```
MATCH(c:Company{companyId:4})<-[re:WORKS_IN]-(p:Person)-[r:HAS_SCORE]->(ps:PerformanceScores)
WITH distinct ps.scoreDate as scoredate
MATCH (ps:PerformanceScores {scoreDate:scoredate})
WITH ps.score as score, scoredate
UNWIND scoredate as x
WITH x,score,scoredate
RETURN avg(score)as average,x as fulldate,["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"][scoredate.month-1] as months,scoredate.year as year order by x
```

So what should be change in the query so that it return the values in the array.

Thanks

Comment: It helps to provide the current results that you get as well as the desired results.

Comment: Is `scoredate` a single date, or a *list* of dates? Your Cypher query is using it in both ways, and if you tried to run it against real data the planner should generate an error without actually executing.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this approach works when you want each of the result columns in an array:

```
MATCH (p:Person) 
RETURN COLLECT(id(p)) AS ids,
       COLLECT(p.name) AS names
```

for your query, this would look like

```
MATCH(c:Company{companyId:4})<-[re:WORKS_IN]-(p:Person)-[r:HAS_SCORE]->(ps:PerformanceScores) 
WITH distinct ps.scoreDate as scoredate 
MATCH (ps:PerformanceScores {scoreDate:scoredate}) 
WITH ps.score as score, scoredate 
UNWIND scoredate as x 
WITH x,score,scoredate 
WITH { average:avg(score),
   fulldate: x,
   months:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"][scoredate.month-1],
   year:scoredate.year 
   } as row order by row.fulldate
RETURN COLLECT (average) as averages, 
 ... etc
```

Comment: Yes, but my results are returning based on the values from the unwind function.

Comment: does not make a difference @UtkarshGoyal.. I edited my answer